# ¿Cómo controlar el acceso a acciones para que sólo vean las vistas y las ejecuten usuarios autorizados en Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Estoy creado una aplicación en `Ruby on Rails` y me ha surgido una duda acerca de controlar los accesos de los usuarios a las diferentes acciones.

En mi caso, no estoy utilizando la gema `Devise`, y tengo un usuario Administrador que va a poder modificar los campos de la Base de datos, crear nuevos objetos, etc. y luego unos usuarios básicos que solo podrán ver los objetos y modificar su propio perfil.

En principio, había pensado hacer un `if` en cada vista solo accesible al administrador preguntando si el usuario `logueado` es o no el administrador de manera que pudiera ver el contenido o mostrarle un error,  pero creo que es una forma muy "chapucera" de hacerlo.

He leído algo de crear una función en el modelo que me diga si el usuario esta o no autorizado y usar un `before_filter` para las funciones de crear y demás pero quería saber vuestra opinión.

Muchas gracias y saludos a todos.

Comment: Bienvenid@ quizas quieras mirar esto -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask esto -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking y esto otro -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour quizas te ayude a la hora de encontrar respuesta y formular futuras preguntas. Saludos

Comment: Te funcionó? Lo importante de esta comunidad es que las respuestas no sirvan solo a la primera persona que hace la pregunta sino también a otros que tengan los mismos problemas más adelante.

Answer (score 2):

Si no quieres usar una gema te sugiero una de las siguientes formas:

1) Usar un *before_action*

Como quieres tener acceso a tu método de autorización en toda la aplicación, creas el método en application_controller.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Tus métodos
  protected
  def authenticate_admin!
    unless current_user.present? && current_user.is_admin?
      flash[:danger] = "No tienes autorización para entrar en esa sección"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Ahora puedes llamar tu método desde cualquier controlador usando un filtro.

```
### Ejemplo
class UserController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, except: [:new, :create, :show]
end
```

En el ejemplo, se asegurará que el usuario sea administrador en todos los métodos de *UsersController* salvo en *new*, *create* y *show*. Obviamente podrías usar el inverso *only* para que el filtro se aplique solo en las acciones elegidas o no especificar nada en cuyo caso se ejecutará antes de todas las acciones.

2) Usar Clases.

Personalmente prefiero separar en controladores distintos las acciones que puede usar un usuario de las exclusivas de administradores. Esto nos permite crear una clase *AdminController* y hacer que los controladores para administradores hereden de esa clase. Abajo un ejemplo usando *User* nuevamente:

```
# config/routes.rb
# Separo rutas para el controlador normal de user y el de administradores

resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show]
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end

# app/controllers/users_controllers.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # acciones abiertas a todos los usuarios
  def new
  end
  def create
  end
  def show
  end
end

# app/controllers/admin_controllers.rb
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  private
  def authenticate_admin!
    unless current_user.signed_in? && current_user.is_admin?
      flash[:danger] = "No tienes autorización para entrar en esa sección"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end

#app/controllers/admin/users_controllers.rb
### Atención: Este controlador hereda de AdminController!
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
  # Ya no necesito el filtro porque lo incluye mi parent_class
  # Tu implementación aquí
end
```

**¿Por qué esta última forma es mi favorita?**

- Nos permite agregar fácilmente otros métodos comunes a los controladores con acciones para administradores.
- Evita errores de seguridad importantes cuando creamos un método y nos olvidamos de incluirlo en el listado de métodos a los que aplica el filtro para verificar un administrador. Al tenerlos completamente separados es muy fácil de ver si nos estamos equivocando.
- Nos permite mantener nuestras rutas bien *RESTful*. Así puedo tener una acción *show* para los usuarios normales y otra para un administrador, sin tener que llamarlo de maneras extrañas (ej: *show_admin*, o *show_for_admin*)
- Mantiene los controladores más cortos y enfocados.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo el uso de la gema "[CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)" que gestiona los permisos de los usuarios de una forma sencilla.

En tu aplicación tendrás una clase Ability en la que defines los diferentes niveles de acceso (o habilidades).

En tus vistas y controladores tendrás esos `if can? :action` que mencionas pero que siempre estarán recogidos en tu clase Ability. En tu clase usuario tendrás que definir las capacidades del usuario con propiedades del tipo `isAdmin`, etc.

De esta forma podrás utilizar filtros en los controladores para definir niveles de acceso en tu app. CanCanCan está muy bien documentado y cuenta con numerosos tutoriales gracias a su excelente comunidad de desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar un hook a nivel controller

[Rails filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Answer (score 0):

1. Instala devise para manejar cuentas de usuario y cancancan para los roles de usuario. En tu gemfile añade:

   gem 'devise'

   gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'

Y en consola realizas:

```
   bundle install
```

Posteriormente en todos tus controladores añade en la segunda linea(despues de la declaracion de clase) lo que vez ahi(el before_action)

```
class Admin::VehiclesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
   ...
```

con esto has filtrado a los usuarios con los que no e indicado que acciones se pueden realizar si esta o no loggueado.

Es importante que en tu archivo routes definas lo que se hara en caso de que no esté logueado, mira:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

En el archivo ability generado por cancancan agregas algo como lo siguiente:

```
if user.role == <nivel de usuario requerido>
  can :manage, :all
else
  can    :read, :all
  cannot :create
  cannot :destroy
  cannot :update
end
```

Esto es a grosso modo lo que tienes que hacer, te recomiendo profundizar un poco mas tu estudio de las gemas.

Aqui podras ver la documentacion completa del devise: [devise docu](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
y aquí la de cancancan [CanCanCan docu](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

Te mando saludos.